# find the range of two arrays with same index values and combine with another array in php

Tags: php, arrays

Find the range between two array with same index values

```php
<?php
$from = Array (1,2);
$to= Array (5,7);
```

this is one more array

```php
$structural_item = array(101,102);


$drawingtype = $_POST["drawingtype"];


$array = range($from , $to);
  foreach( $structural_item as $structuralitem ) {
  echo  $drawingtype .'-'. $structuralitem .'-'.$row. "\n";
    }
   foreach( $array as $row ) {

    echo  $drawingtype .'-'. $structuralitem .'-'.$row. "\n";
    }

?>
```

now I want output like  with same index number range

**range between two arrays with same index values**

**combine with another array as 101 and 102**
range from

```php
[0] => 1
[1] => 5
1-101-1
1-101-2
1-101-3
1-101-4
1-101-5
array(1,2,3,4,5)
```

and

```php
[0] => 2
[1] => 7
1-102-2
1-102-3
1-102-4
1-102-5
1-102-6
1-102-7

array(2,4,5,6,7)
```

Output:

[image: see the out put]

Comment: Your expected output is unclear. Does all of that need to be in a single array?

Comment: range of two arrays with another array i need to combine for example its look like this
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
            [4] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 7
            [3] => 8
            [4] => 9
            [5] => 10
        )

)
0-101-Array
0-102-Array

Comment: Please edit your question to add clarification (the `Edit` link can be found at the bottom). Comments aren't suitable for examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to php.net for a [range](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) function input must be ***string|int|float*** for $start and $end parameter, so you can write your own function something like this :

```
function range_array(array $from, array $to, $step = []) {
    if(sizeof($from) !== sizeof($to))
        throw "From array and to array must be of same size";
        $return = [];
    foreach ($from as $k => $v) {
        if (!$step[$k])
            $step[$k] = 1;
        $return[] = range($v, $to[$k], $step[$k]);
    }
    return $return;
}

$from = Array(1, 2);
$to = Array(5, 7);
$array = range_array($from, $to);
print_r($array);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
            [4] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 5
            [4] => 6
            [5] => 7
        )
)
```

UPDATE:
If i get it right

```
$from = Array(1, 2);
$to = Array(5, 7);
$array = range_array($from, $to);

$result = [];
$drawingtype = 1;
$structural_item = array(101, 102);
foreach ($structural_item as $key => $structuralitem) {
    foreach ($array[$key] as $value) {
        echo $drawingtype . "-" . $structuralitem . "-" . $value . "<br/>";
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
1-101-1
1-101-2
1-101-3
1-101-4
1-101-5
1-102-2
1-102-3
1-102-4
1-102-5
1-102-6
1-102-7
```

Comment: @thejashwinil can you update your question, didn't get any ot that

Comment: @thejashwinil i've updated the answer, still requested result is unclear

Comment: am getting the error in $array = range_array($from, $to);

Comment: @thejashwinil so copy the `function range_array` ... above

Comment: am not getting wat to do after function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228413/discussion-between-thejashwini-l-and-angel-bonev).